# camel-bindy Multiple models in the same package is not woking

Tags: spring, integration, apache-camel, fixed-length-record

I am using camel-bindy component.

I have 2 model file in same package.

When i remove 1 model file in package it's working fine but when i put both the files inside same package it's not working.

i am using camel 2.12.3 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason might be exactly that, the two classes in the same package.
Try moving one to another package + see [comment from Claus Ibsen](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Bindy-not-able-to-handle-multiple-annotated-classes-td5752586.html).